# Help with Report Logic (Expressions/Parentheses)

Tags: formula

I am working on a report that I need to filter with 2 separate data points.  I need to capture the following filter statements:

(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 6 AND 8)

or

(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 7 AND 9)

I have tried multiple ways to write it yet I am always missing some component in the data.

Any help is appreciated!  @sfdcfox I see you are an expert in these things!  I will owe you a coffee or 10 for sure if you can help!

[image]

Comment: Did you try `1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND  ( (6 AND 8) OR ( 7 AND 9) )`. look at the bracket placement.

Comment: I did - and it still leaves out some of the brands from the (6 and 8) or the (7 and 9) filters.  I swear I have stared at it so much I am going nuts.  1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND ((6 AND 8) OR (7 AND 9))